# hessian metric, Gaussian curvature, mean curvature, Ricci tensor

Tags: differential-geometry

Assume that on $R^n$ we consider a Hessian type metric, that is $(g_{ij})=c(f_{ij})$, where $c>0$ is a constant and $f(x)$ is a $C^2$ function defined on $R^n$.

1. What is the Gaussian curvature of $R^n$ in this metric ?
2. What is the (mean) curvature of $f(x)=const$ in this metric ?
3. What are the conditions on $f(x)$ that force the Ricci tensor of $R^n$, in this metric, to be non-negative or equal to zero (in the sense of tensors) ?

Is there any book/article where such formulas are already derived (at least for $R^2$, with a hessian type metric) ? (this is my first contact with tensor calculus!)

PS: For the beginning, let's also assume that $g=det(g_{ij})$ is constant, in case this assumption makes some answers more clear.